# PHP Dynamic Count Function

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make ONE dynamic function for count in mysql:

functions.php:

```
  function countEntries($table, $where = '', $what = '')
  {
      if (!empty($where) && isset($what)) {
          $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table . "  WHERE " . $where . " = '" . $what . "' LIMIT 1";
      } else{
          $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table . " LIMIT 1";
      }
      $record = query($q);
      $total = fetchrow($record);
      return $total[0];
  }
```

HTML Code:

```
<?php echo countEntries("news", "category", "1"); ?>
<?php echo countEntries("post", "type", "Sports"); ?>
```

But still got blank page without any error!!!

Comment: what do you mean if this will work? why not try it?

Comment: You forgot to close else with a `}` <------

Comment: and why don't you give to whole condition in 1 variable? you are not manipulating that, so, use `$condition`.

Comment: It'll work, but it'll feel pretty limited in a few months :)

Comment: You don't need a `{}` if there is only a single line in the else part. You can see that there is no `{` either. So it would not be a problem.

Comment: Please note that your code is open to SQL injections. Escape/parametize your queries instead.

Comment: Better call it `entryExist()`, you are not really counting when using `LIMIT 1`. Your `function` will only `return` 1 or 0

Comment: you have a } to remove. The one after the else

Comment: What is the code of the function `query()` and the function `fetchrow()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

```
function countEntries($table, $where = '', $what = '')
      {
          if (!empty($where) && isset($what)) {
              $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM " . $table . "  WHERE " . $where . " = '" . $what . "' LIMIT 1";
          } else{
              $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM " . $table . " LIMIT 1";
          }
          $record = query($q);
          $total = fetchrow($record);
          return $total['count'];
      }
```

Here you give an alias to the count(*) and use that to access the returned result as $total['count'].
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> First things you forgot to close else past,second just add this line "**ini_set("display_errors", 1);**" at the top of your php.this will shows the error in your php.

Your code:

```
function countEntries($table, $where = '', $what = '')
{
  if (!empty($where) && isset($what)) {
      $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table . "  WHERE " . $where . " = '" . $what . "' LIMIT 1";
  } else
      $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table . " LIMIT 1";
  }
  $record = query($q);
  $total = fetchrow($record);
  return $total[0];
}
```

my code:

```
   function countEntries($table, $where = '', $what = '')
      {
      if (!empty($where) && isset($what)) {
          $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM " . $table . "  WHERE " . $where . " = '" . $what . "' LIMIT 1";
      } else{
          $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM " . $table . " LIMIT 1";
      }
      $record = query($q);
      $total = fetchrow($record);
      return $total['count'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, Its working well now:

```
function countEntries($table, $where, $what)
{
  if (!empty($where) && isset($what)) {
      $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table . "  WHERE " . $where . " = '" . $what . "' LIMIT 1";
  } else
    $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table . " LIMIT 1";
    $record = mysql_query($q);
    $total = mysql_fetch_array($record);
    return $total[0];
}


echo countEntries('news', "type", "sport");
```

Comment: You should add a note detailing what you did to make it work.